# Pivot_longer in R with names_pattern

Tags: r, regex, pivot

I have very limited experience with regular expressions and I'm having trouble using them with names_pattern.

My data frame is in wide format with the columns titled 
X1998..YR1998.    X1997..YR1997.     X1996..YR1996.
etc.

I want to pivot to a long format with row for years being 1998, 1997, 1996, etc. This is what I tried.

```r
df.gdp.long <- pivot_longer(df.gdp, cols=starts_with("X"), names_to=c('year',"year"),
                            names_prefix="X", names_pattern = 'X(.)..YR(.).',
                            values_to="gdp")
```

However, right now the rows say X1998..YR1998. etc. Do you have a suggestion using names pattern? Or anything else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show a small example and expected output Try `pivot_longer(df.gdp, everything(), names_to = c( 'grp', '.value'), names_pattern = 'X(\\d{4})\\.{2}YR(\\d{4}).')`

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` i.e `dput(head(df.gdp))` ?

Comment: Isn't it easier to assign a more regular set of column names first? You can then use simple `tidyselect` helper functions to grab the columns you would like to `pivot_longer`. For instance, replace all column names with e.g. YRxxxx where xxxx is the relevant year. You can use substring functions to do that.

Comment: Substr could be used to extract the years from the column names in this way `names(df.gdp) <- substr(names(df.gdp),10,14)`

Comment: Becky, you've had two requests for sample data, is there a reason you are choosing to not make this easier? (Hint: people want to help you ... make it **easy** for them. Don't make them **guess** what your data actually looks like.)

Comment: Try `(?<=X)([0-9]{4})(?=[.]{2}YR\1)` value need is match or grp1 the same as

Answer (score -1):

```
df.gdp.long <- df.gdp %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(),names_to = c('year'), names_pattern = '(\\d+)',values_to="gdp")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
Kind Regards.